# is there a kind of property only set in a web control constructor?

Tags: asp.net, constructor, web-controls

I have a WebControl and it has a property. However, value of this property should not be changed once the control has been constructed... in other words, the property can be set only in some code like:

```
<ct:Acontrol ID="xxx" Aproperty="xxx"  runat="server"></ct:Acontrol>
```

but not:

```
xxx.Aproperty=...
```

so what is the normal way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties that you are using in markup must be public properties with a public getter *and* setter. There is no special syntax for "only set this once".

What you *can* do is check in the setter whether it was already set and if so, not set to the new value.

```
private string _aProperty;

public string Aproperty
{
    get { return _aProperty;}
    set
    {
       if(_aProperty == null)
       {
          _aProperty = value;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...this is acceptable for a string... just the property is a bool and default to false... i ll think about this direction though

Comment: @shrimprice - You should be able to use a `bool?` and instead of the nullity check test for `HasValue`, though I didn't try this myself.

Comment: yes...it also needs to tell whether the vaule is default false or not, and the set is only allowed in the constructor...i ll think about it... thanks

Comment: though the code is not exactly what I want, it can solve the problem. so i ll mark it as the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
xxx.Attributes("Aproperty")
```

Answer (score 0):

All ASP.NET markup attributes are set as properties after the constructor is executed. You can select specific read-only properties to be set only in the constructor by using sub-classes of the control.

```
<!-- Aproperty=xxx -->
<ct:Acontrolxxx ID="xxx" runat="server"></ct:Acontrolyyy> 

<!-- Aproperty=yyy -->
<ct:Acontrolyyy ID="yyy" runat="server"></ct:Acontrolxxx>
```

```
public class Acontrolxxx : Acontrolbase 
 {  
       public Acontrolxxx () {  base.Aproperty = xxx; }
 }
```

Comment: not sure how you hide the property in the derived class... also the Controlbase can still be used which is not quite safe... this way looks a little too much... but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You can mark the property `internal` and the base class `abstract`.

Answer (score 0):

The property is probably using a combination of the `EditorBrowsable` and `DesignerSerializationVisibility` attributes:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

The `DesignerSerializationVisibility` attribute shows the property in markup, and the `EditorBrowsable` attribute hides the property in code-behind.

Comment: it looks like EditorBrowsable would allow the code to compile... so this way still has problems... thanks for letting me know this attribute though.

Comment: Maybe try adding the `[DesignOnly(true)]` attribute too?